# How to terminate running a Java method or Java class in JSF (PrimeFaces 3.0)

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, primefaces

I have a Java method which runs approximate one or two hours.I made an web ui using jsf and primeface for this.I would like to terminate and restart the method using commandButtons. How do I do that?

I use GlassFish server.

Comment: wow, JSF 3, you're from the future, I suppose ;)

Comment: Sorry I mean Primeface 3.0 :). I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Look over the [PrimeFaces ShowCase at their command button](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf).  Gather ideas.
- Establish (the use of) an application-level context where a reference to work/thread may be kept.  Should this be session based?  What's the life-time of a session?

#### Option: Work - staying on the Java EE path

- Review relevant [blogs](http://danielveselka.blogspot.com/2012/03/schedule-jobs-with-workmanager.html) and [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/resource/spi/work/package-summary.html)

#### Option: Thread - texas solution: get er done

- Read [Thread javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).  Pay careful attention to [interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) and [isInterrupted](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a long-running method/job, it's good practice be able to stop (or pause, etc) the job. This is typically done by letting the job run inside its own thread, and to let it frequently check a "stop" flag, which can be set by any other thread. Your command button can set the flag when it is clicked by a user.

This is a common approach to let to threads communicate with each other.

Good luck,
Tom

Comment: Any other suggestion would be helpful :)